# Hausdorff distance between two convex bodies

Tags: convex-geometry, hausdorff-distance

I consider all the convex bodies of constant width in $\mathbb{R^2}$ (to fix ideas I take the width equal 1 )
I consider that all these bodies are centered in O( O is the Origine  the Cartesian coordinate system in |R^2)

my question is :

**what is the upper bound of the Hausdorff distance between the disk and any convex body of constante width (width=1)?**